# neo4j failing to start after disk full

Tags: java, neo4j

i had the /var disk full on my debian server and neo4j stopped as expected. I freed up the space on the disk but the neo4j server does not start throwing the error given below in the logs. I don't have any java or neo4j process running on the server that i may kill.

Things were stable with my neo4j setup for the past 6 months with around 1000 nodes. I am little novice on the java side so please let me know if i have missed out on anything basic.

Output on command line: service neo4j-service restart

> Restarting Neo4j Graph Database: neo4jWARNING: Max 1024 open files
>   allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual. WARNING!
>   You are using an unsupported Java runtime. 
>   * Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) 7 to run Neo4j Server. Download "Java Platform (JDK) 7" from:
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
>   * Please see http://docs.neo4j.org/ for Neo4j Server installation instructions. Using additional JVM arguments:  -server
>   -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user process [4733]... waiting for
>   server to be ready..... Failed to start within 120 seconds. Neo4j
>   Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.  failed!

Logfile:

```
Sep 26, 2014 3:31:38 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
Sep 26, 2014 3:33:00 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
WARNING: You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
Sep 26, 2014 3:33:00 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
Sep 26, 2014 3:33:03 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: 
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:218)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:330)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:198)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.recovery.StoreRecoverer.recover(StoreRecoverer.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.run(PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PreFlightTasks.run(PreFlightTasks.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.runPreflightTasks(AbstractNeoServer.java:333)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:152)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager@61615142' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:509)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:307)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Unable to start TM
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.openLog(TxManager.java:824)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.start(TxManager.java:198)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:503)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Branch[����] found for [GlobalId[NENEOK|5930761323375553953|5569093129887285248|13248], BranchId[ ]] but no record list found in map
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxLog.readBranchAddRecordInto(TxLog.java:520)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxLog.getDanglingRecords(TxLog.java:440)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxLog.recreateActiveTransactionState(TxLog.java:133)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxLog.<init>(TxLog.java:128)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.openLog(TxManager.java:796)
    ... 14 more

Sep 26, 2014 3:33:03 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
```

I am using an openjdk 1.7 runtime environment which i think i should upgrade but i don't understand what is the cause of the error since everything was working fine before. Thanks for any help!

Comment: was able to start the service by deleting the transaction logs - tm_tx_log.1 or tm_tx_log.2: not sure if this was the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never ever manually modify anything inside the `graph.db` directory unless you're 100% sure what you're doing.

To prevent the datastore directory from continuously growing check your setting for `keep_logical_logs` in `neo4j.properties`, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-logical-logs.html.

Unless you require logical logs for online backup or cluster synchronization, you might be save deleting `nioneo_logical.log.v*` files. Make sure to have a backup first!

Also check your settings for open file limits, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/linux-performance-guide.html#_setting_the_number_of_open_files.

There used to be a outdated version of Neo4j having a bug that might corrupt your datastore when running out of disc space. If that has happened to you either need to manually fix it on a binary level (which requires a lot of knowledge on Neo4j internals) or restore a previous backup from a time before you run out of disc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.my neo4j version is 2.0.1

Comment: I tried to increase open file limits following the instructions given in the link and restarted the server but i still get the WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. any idea what i could have missed.

Comment: On Ubuntu (and recent Debian probably as well) you need to change your settings in `/etc/security/limits.d/neo4j.conf`. Be sure to use the correct user name in this file.

Comment: Thanks again! both the open file warning and java warning have been resolved now. but a strange thing happened earlier today  when i restarted my server after another load testing with around 10,000 relationships inserted, neo4j won't start. This time it does not even throw anything in the logs other than the startup timed-out. Any idea what could have caused it?

Comment: ...but the messages.log says unclean shutdown and unable to open lucene log should i be deleting lucene logs too

Comment: if you just use schema indexes you can drop the `graph.db/schema` folder. Schema indexes should be recreated upon startup. Make a backup copy before doing so.

Comment: I dropped the schema folder still the service won't start..it works though if i move the lucene logs to another location somewhere else. But this is not a good practice right? what else could i have done. I can copy back the lucene logs if you have another alternative. Its mainly the active log that seems to be the problem.